# Can't Compile LESS to CSS with LESS2CSS Plugin on Sublime Text 3 Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, sublimetext3, therubyracer

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Mac OS Yosemite. I want to use LESS2CSS package but it not working. Here are the errors it gives:

```
WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- v8 (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/java_script.rb:9:in `default_context_wrapper'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/java_script.rb:17:in `context_wrapper'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/loader.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less.rb:14:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less.rb:14:in `<module:Less>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/less-2.6.0/bin/lessc:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/lessc:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/lessc:23:in `<main>'
```

I've installed `Node.js` and installed `less`, but it is still not working.

Comment: So you mean you already have installed `therubyracer` gem then?

Comment: Yes sir. Installed on my mac.

Comment: checkout here: https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/issues/47 you might get some solution. Also, me not sir :P